# Icons missing after migration to other domain

Tags: wordpress, url, fonts, migration, themes

I've migrated a website from location "B" to location "A". The only problem i've got, the 'osfont' icons are not showing up. When i check console i've got this message:

**downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "osfont" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:3): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://B.com/blog/wp-content/themes/neptune-by-osetin/assets/fonts/osfont/osfont.woff?z52hks23**

The theme-support said it's a server problem. But my questing, how can i get ride of the old URL that's pointing to domain "B". I have the same path on domain "A" but can't find where to edit this line.

I don't want to use acces-control-allow-origin because the website on location "B" will be removed after succesfull migration.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Better Search and Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin after domain transfers. It lets you search database WordPress database tables for the old domain and replace it with the new one. It lets you select within which tables you want to search and replace. I usually just select all tables. It also lets you do a test run, so that you can see how many occurrences you have before doing an actual replace. Take a backup of the database before you do an actual replace, just to be safe. Also be careful of trailing slashes - they must be exactly same in both the search string and the replace string. I managed to mess up once and did not have a database backup :(

```
search for:
olddomain.com
replace with:
newdomain.com
```

Comment: I already tried the Better Search and Replace,but thanks for thinking. It has changed 16 tables in wp_posts and wp_options. I think the old url inside a CSS file or something. When i switch, inside my template setting, to use custom font; osfont, it shows the icons perfectly. The only problem is that my other template styling is gone.

Is there no other way to debug which file is used?